# IE Mystery Click Event Reloading IFRAME

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a table on a page loaded into an IFRAME which has a GET query string in the calling URL to direct the proper table data.  In addition, I have a jQuery system which updates the cells of the table as well as posting data to a PHP script to update a database.

On FF and Chrome, the update happens as requested, and the table cell text is updated correctly per the jQuery.  No problems.

On IE, after the script is run and the data is updated, the browser reloads the IFRAME content using the URL without a query string (which obviously breaks the display.)  IE's Web Developer Network Monitor shows the IFRAME page request and states that it originated with a click on a hyper-link (which obviously did not happen).

**UPDATE** *On further testing using cookies to retain the query string data, it appears that something in the post is causing the entire frame to reload. I have comments out all of the code in the case "11" section so that only the post happens.  Still reloading.*

Why does IE fire this 'click' event to reload the page, and why would it only be using the query string-less part of the URL?

Here is the part of the script that posts my change to a PHP script and updates the table cell with the new data(excuse my mess, still in development)

```
//Beginning here, the code attaches the change handler to a dynamically generated input or select form element
//The 'cell' element below is a cache of an earlier element (the original table cell)
$('#updForm').on('change','input, select', function() {
       updCell = $(this);
       //POST data to ajax.php for update and audit logging
       $.post('/inc/ajax.php',{
            'called': 'stdUpdate',
            'type': type,
            'field': name,
            'idx': record,
            'table': table,
            'value': updCell.val().trim().toUpperCase()
       }, function(data){
                switch (data){
                     case "10": alert('Updated the record, but the audit logging failed.'); break;
                     case "01": alert('Did not report an updated record, but the audit logged the transaction.'); break;
                     case "00": alert('No records were updated or logged.'); break;
                     case "11":
                          cell.text(updCell.val().trim().toUpperCase());
                          $('tbody tr:eq(' + rowId + ') td:eq(' + colId + ')').text(updCell.val().trim().toUpperCase());
                          //Resize row if height increased
                          $('table.DTFC_Cloned tbody tr:eq(' + rowId + '), tbody tr:eq(' + rowId + ')').height(cell.height());  
                          //Resize column if width increased
                          $('table.DTFC_Cloned thead th.' + name + ', tbody th.' + name).width(cell.width());  
                          //Close the dialog and clear the dynamic section
                          $('#table-updater').dialog('close');
                          cell.css({
                             'background-color' : '#c6efce',
                             'color' : '#006100'  
                          }).animate({
                             'background-color' : 'transparent',
                             'color' : 'black'  
                          }, 1000);
                          $('#updForm').off('change','input, select');
                          $('#updForm').html('');
                          break;
                     default: alert('An invalid response of "' + data + '" was returned from the database.');          
                }
           });
      });
```

Comment: <troll>It's Internet Explorer, dude! You're lost. </troll>. If I remember they are some 'issues' with the onClick() in old IE version. Anyway, jQuery 2.x doesn't support IE 6/7/8. So maybe the problem is there? I'm more a backend developer, I hope it's give you a way to follow. In addition maybe it's work on specific IE version.

Comment: I hate having to support Internet Exploder, but in a corp world it is what it is.  I'm using 1.10.2 for compatibility with older browsers.  Thanks though.

Comment: The problem occurred on all versions of Internet Explorer?

Comment: All that I've tested to this point (11, 10, 9).  See update above for additional testing info.

Comment: Found my answer.

It appears that Internet Explorer treats an enter press in a form as a submit and automatically sends the page back to itself (even though there is no action or method defined).  Adding e.preventDefault(); into the previous handler (not shown) forced IE to use the code as written.

Apparently FF and Chrome don't follow the same logic.